# How to fill null values of a feature present in polars dataframe with median values of the feature?

Tags: python, python-polars, data-preprocessing

I'm a pandas user but due to the advantages of polars dataframes over pandas, i tried switching to polars. When I did the switching, I encountered this problem of not knowing how to fill the null values of a feature with it median values based on another correlated feature values.

Take the example shown below:

| Name | IMDB Score | Meta Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 8 | 86 |
| C | 8 | 90 |
| D | 8 | null |
| E | 8 | 91 |
| D | 7 | 66 |
| D | 3 | 44 |

I know in pandas we can do something like this to fill the 'Meta Score' feature with median value

```
df.groupby('IMDB Score')['Meta Score'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
```

Now I want to know how can we do the same within polars dataframes.

Comment: Next time you post a question it would be great if you can add a code snippet that generates an input DataFrame. Now I have to manually type in your data to be able to help you.

Comment: OK. thanks for the advice.. I will definitely add my code snippets in future.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a window function (called with `.over`) to compute the median values per group `"IMDB Score"`.

`pl.col("Meta Score").median().over("IMDB Score")`

That result can be the input of a `fill_null` expression.

Combining that we have:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["B", "C", "D", "E", "D", "D"],
    "IMDB Score": [8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 3],
    "Meta Score": [86, 90, None, 91, 66, 44],
})

df.with_column(
    pl.col("Meta Score").fill_null(
        pl.col("Meta Score").median().over("IMDB Score")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌──────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ Name ┆ IMDB Score ┆ Meta Score │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ str  ┆ i64        ┆ f64        │
╞══════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ B    ┆ 8          ┆ 86.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C    ┆ 8          ┆ 90.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ D    ┆ 8          ┆ 90.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ E    ┆ 8          ┆ 91.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ D    ┆ 7          ┆ 66.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ D    ┆ 3          ┆ 44.0       │
└──────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```